# Could Adiantum encryption cause SSD failure?

Tags: encryption, ssd

I recently encrypted a brand new Samsung 870 QVO 8TB SSD with an Adiantum cipher and within a day of using it, the drive failed. It is currently completely unrecognised.

The Host OS was Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 running on a Pi 4B. The filesystem was ext4 and I must have copied about 900GB onto the drive before it died.

Could the encryption have caused it to go belly up or was it just a freak occurence?

Comment: It is nearly next to impossible to say if the encryption caused the drive to go belly up since this is only the first occurrence that you have had so there is nothing to base it off of.  Chances are that this is a freak occurrence that happened.  Reading up about that cipher states that they designed it to be used in more lightweight environments that use the same technology as SSDs like in Cell Phones, etc.

Comment: Fair point. I only ended up using Adantium as the Pi doesn't have HW support for the usual suspects. I'm just trying to weigh my options on whether it'd be worth going with the same setup again or if I should look into another drive and cipher.